# Writing the relative path in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

While uploading image i have this path:

```
public function uploadImage()
{
     $target_dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\application\public\newuploads';
     ...
```

It worked fine.
But, when i uploaded to production server i change it to:

```
 $target_dir = 'www.mywebsite.com\public\newuploads';
```

It gives me error:

> move_uploaded_file(www.mywebsite.com\public\newuploads/1487912832.
>   jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How can i write the relative path instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never hardcode the path. Use [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path) helper to get path to the public directory:

```
public_path('newuploads')
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use any static path for local or live server.

Laravel provides lot of functions to do this:

Just use it like:

```
$target_dir = public_path()."/newuploads";
```

Use the same on local and live environment.

This will work.

For More Details And Laravel Helper Functions You Can Check This:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your production server, you may have a different root directory. That being said, instead of using a full folder path, you can use the public path root such as

```
$target_dir = '/newuploads';
```

That way if the underlying OS and file system changes, your site operations are intact.